# How do I create a pointer to an object in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C#, but I've done a decent amount of programming in C.

I have a library with two levels of classes inside it where Level 2 inherits properties from Level 1, like below.

```
public class Level1
{
    int a;
    int b;
    string c;
}
// inherits from Level1
public class Level2a : Level1
{
    string d;
    bool e;
}
public class Level2b : Level1
{
    int f;
    bool g;
}
```

What I want is to create a generic object that can essentially "point" to either a Level2a or Level2b instantiated object based on a switch case.

```
Level2a myObjectA = new Level2a();
Level2b myObjectB = new Level2b();

myObjectA.c = "This is ";        // c is inherited from Level1
myObjectA.d = "my string";
bool myVariable = 0;
var myGeneric;     // not sure how to declare this

switch(myVariable) {
    case 0: myGeneric = myObjectA; break; // not sure how to assign this
    case 1: myGeneric = myObjectB; break;
    default: break;
}

// Then I should be able to do this:
Console.WriteLine(myGeneric.c + myGeneric.d);
// Console prints out "This is my string"
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object pointers(object\*) in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455252/object-pointersobject-in-c-sharp)

Comment: just declare `myGeneric` as `Level1` but that won't always work - you should just use an interface or something like that.

Comment: Btw, it's better if you don't try to bring idioms from C to your C# code.

Comment: @DanielA.White I did try that, but I do need to be able to reference Level2  stuff from myGeneric. What do you mean by use an interface?

Comment: Not sure to understand ; if you print `myGeneric.d` myGeneric must be a Level2a. What do you expect as result if it were a Level2b instead ?

Comment: _"pointer"_ or _reference_?  In c# variables link to other objects using safe .NET  _references_ which are valid even if the object is moved about by .NET.  _"Pointers"_ are rarely used in .NET and are used for obtaining low-level unsafe addresses to objects in memory usually for the purpose of inter-operating with native code.

Comment: Side note: @driedell,  please don't use "generic" as "something" when speaking about C# - "generic"/"generics" has very specific meaning and unless you talking about C# generics it will confuse readers.

Comment: @driedell I know what are you looking for. take a look at my post. you dont want the property, you want the method to work differently

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good to know, thanks. Like I said, I'm new to C# :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable of type `Level1`:

```
Level2a myObjectA = new Level2a();
Level2b myObjectB = new Level2b();

...

Level1 myGeneric = myObjectA;  // Assigning more derived object to less derived variable
```

It should be noted that this will not work:

```
Console.WriteLine(myGeneric.c + myGeneric.d);
```

Since `Level1` doesn't have a `d` member, you'll get a **compile error**. You can cast it to the more derived type if you want, but you're breaking OOP principles at that point:

```
Console.WriteLine(myGeneric.c + ((Level2a)myGeneric).d);
```

Comment: I have tried this technique, and I do get the compiler error at that point which says `myGeneric` has no definition for d. Is there another way to do this within OOP rules?

Comment: Depends on the context, but I'm sure there is. I don't understand why you're trying to use `d` in the general case. You should only need to use `d` if you know you're dealing with a `Level2a` object, right? You could create a `virtual` property for `d` in `Level1` that just returns some default value and then override it in `Level2A` to actually do something meaningful I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since both sub classes inherit from the super class `Level1` you can do something like:

```
Level2a myObjectA = new Level2a();
Level2b myObjectB = new Level2b();

Level1 myObjectIReallyLike;
switch(myVariable) {
    case 0:
        myObjectIReallyLike = myObjectA;
        break;
    case 2:
        myObjectIReallyLike = myObjectB;
        break;
 }
```

If you're using this for a game (unity, cry engine?), you might want to define a common interface, instead of up-inheriting until you've reached 500 levels.

Comment: They do inherit from the the 'Level1' superclass, but 'myObjectIReallyLike' needs to be able to access properties from the 'Level2' object it points to, not just properties from 'Level1'.

Comment: Then you should check out ``typeof(aVariable)``, ``aVariable as Level2b``, ``(Level2b) aVariable`` and ``aVariable is Level2b``. Casting in C# is fun and games, actually and the language has tons of tools to do that from within the syntax. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms173105.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
It is a bit out of scope of this post.

Comment: That won't work with the OP's final statement `Console.WriteLine(myGeneric.c + myGeneric.d);`.  Property `d` is defined on class `Level2a` not `Level1`

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement polymorphism. You need to new objects by inherited class and then assign them to a variable from the base class. like this.

```
Level1 myObjectA = new Level2a();
Level1 myObjectB = new Level2b();

myObjectA.a = 1;
myObjectB.a =2;
```

you can even add them to a List and call methods that has been registered in base class.

C# works with pointers by default, so it will automatically use override methods if any.
I change your code

**Edit:**
Apparently my code was not clear enough. take a look at the code below

```
public class Level1
{
   public int a;
  public  int b;
    public string c;

    public virtual string GetString()
    {
      return c;
    }

}
// inherits from Level1
public class Level2a : Level1
{
   public string d;
   public bool e;
    public override string GetString()
    {
      return base.GetString() + d ;
    }    
}
public class Level2b : Level1
{
   public int f;
   public bool g;

}
```

---

```
Level1 obj= new Level2a();
 ....
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetString());
 // This is my string
obj= new Level2b();
.....
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetString());
// This is
```

Comment: Not sure why the need to rewrite the OP's code.  You haven't addressed the final problem of `Console.WriteLine(myGeneric.c + myGeneric.d);`

Comment: @MickyD there is no need to address the problem line by line. It clear for me that what he needs, he just don't know it exactly. you never can address myGeneric.d when you want to run it on a Level2b object.

Comment: @MickyD hmmm, thanks for mentioning it. How about now? is it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your precise question is `dynamic` which will delay all type checking till run-time and let your compile and run code successfully:

```
dynamic myGeneric = null;
```

Notes: this is generally not C# way of doing it and some refactoring of the code (possibly with making interface for both classes) may give you strongly typed code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned all over, you need interfaces--and some funny explicit implementation and casting. C# doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes, but you can include behavior from multiple interfaces in a class.

```
using System;

namespace tests
{
    public interface ILevel1
    {
        int a { get; set; }
        int b { get; set; }
        string c { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ILevel2a
    {
        string d { get; set; }
        int e { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ILevel2b
    {
        int f { get; set; }
        bool g { get; set; }
    }

    public class Level2a : ILevel1, ILevel2a {
        int ILevel1.a { get; set; }
        int ILevel1.b { get; set; }
        string ILevel1.c { get; set; }

        string ILevel2a.d { get; set; }
        int ILevel2a.e { get; set; }
    }

    public class Level2b : ILevel1, ILevel2b
    {
        int ILevel1.a { get; set; }
        int ILevel1.b { get; set; }
        string ILevel1.c { get; set; }

        int ILevel2b.f { get; set; }
        bool ILevel2b.g { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Level2a myObjectA = new Level2a();
            Level2b myObjectB = new Level2b();

            ((ILevel1)myObjectA).c = "This is ";
            ((ILevel2a)myObjectA).d = "my string";

            ((ILevel1)myObjectB).c = "Hey, I'm a Level2b!";

            int myVariable = 0;

            dynamic myObject = null; // declare as dynamic

            switch (myVariable)
            {
            case 0: myObject = myObjectA; break;
            case 1: myObject = myObjectB; break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            if (myObject is Level2a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((ILevel1)myObject).c + ((ILevel2a)myObject).d);
            }
            else if (myObject is Level2b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((ILevel1)myObject).c);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, beut there's never going to be a "d" member on a Level2b instance--to skip the test you would have to make "d" a member of ILevel1 or ILevel2b.