# Is there a way to delegate handling of a property to another property?

Tags: c#

Simply, I want to do:

```
class Foo {
  Bar myBar;
  
  // I want to replace:
  string Name { 
    get => myBar.Name;
    set => myBar.Name = value;
  }

  // ...with something like:
  string Address => myBar.Address; // this only implements 'get', but I want 'set' as well
}
```

I assume the answer to this is boringly "no, and no plans to do this", but thought I'd ask just the same :)

Comment: Is your `Foo` class just wrapper around `Bar`?

Comment: Get and set are just wrapper functions. Write them full out and you can do whatever you want in them. Although it wouldnt follow any known coding standard, it would work.

Comment: You could go all the unmanaged/unsafe way, but I personally would stick with a property or check the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455252/object-pointersobject-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have linked a related/possible duplicate but I would suggest using the property. It allows you to later control concurrency if needed

Comment: The short answer is no. The way `Name` is written is what you have to do.

Comment: "*I assume the answer to this is boringly "no, and no plans to do this", but thought I'd ask just the same*" => why asking that on Stack Overflow instead of Microsoft if you know the answer ? But... do you have idea of how to do that ? How can we write this more simply ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier borrowing from Kotlin, `string Address by myBar.Address;`, if you just want a "how is this even possible" sort of answer.

Comment: If you are really really serious, then one possibility is to use [aspect oriented programming](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1223461/AOP-Method-and-property-interception-in-Csharp). Another - T4 templates (to generate whole wrapper class). But imho `Name` property is beautiful as it is.

Comment: @Sinatr Those are some really interesting options! Seems more than I want for my simple case, but good reading. Agree with the consensus here that as-is is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the answer is basically 'no' (see comments). There are some rather complicated methods to facilitate this effect with [aspect oriented programming](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1223461/AOP-Method-and-property-interception-in-Csharp) or T4 templates.